# R: Histograma de frecuencias relativas

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente vector:

```
crias = c(4, 7, 2, 8, 6, 7, 2, 2, 9, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 6, 4, 7, 8, 4, 8)
```

Cuyos valores quiero agrupar según los intervalos delimitados por los siguientes extremos:

```
L = c(1.95, 3.45, 4.95, 6.45, 7.95, 9.45)
```

Así que hago uso de la función `cut()`:

```
criasInt = cut(crias, 
               breaks = L, #Extremos de los intervalos
               right = FALSE #Intervalos cerrados por la izquierda
              )
```

Calculo las frecuencias absolutas:

```
ni = table(criasInt)

[1.95,3.45) [3.45,4.95) [4.95,6.45) [6.45,7.95) [7.95,9.45) 
          4           4           5           3           4
```

Y las relativas:

```
fi = prop.table(ni)

[1.95,3.45) [3.45,4.95) [4.95,6.45) [6.45,7.95) [7.95,9.45) 
       0.20        0.20        0.25        0.15        0.20
```

Sin embargo, si represento la información mediante un histograma:

```
hist(crias,
     breaks = L, #Extremos de los intervalos
     freq = FALSE, #Frecuencias relativas
     right = FALSE, #Intervalos cerrados por la izquierda
     xaxt = "n", #Elimina la leyenda del eje X
     xlab = "Intervalos", ylab = "",
     col = "lightblue",
     main = "Frecuencias relativas"
    )
axis(1, at = L) #Intervalos como leyenda del eje X
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tamaño de las barras parece el apropiado, pero la escala del eje Y, dado `fi`, no es la que espero. ¿A qué puede deberse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el argumento `freq = FALSE` indica a `histogram` que en lugar de usar las frecuencias calcule y utilice la densidad (usando `density` internamente). Las barras están bien porque las densidades son proporcionales a las frecuencias, pero la escala no porque en las densidades transformas de tal modo que el área del gráfico sume 1 (aproximando a una función de probabilidad, pero... sin función).

La solución que le encuentro es hacer un barplot con las barras pegadas, así tienes más control. Sí, un barplot no es conceptualmente lo mismo que un histograma, pero visualmente es muy parecido si pegas las barras.

```
barplot(fi,   #La tabla de la que tomas los valores para controlar la altura en y y las etiquetas en x
        space = 0, #Para que las barras estén pegadas
        xlab = "Intervalos", ylab = "",
        col = "lightblue",
        main = "Frecuencias relativas")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema está en las etiquetas, en tu gráfico tienes 6 en los puntos de separación y con `barplot` tienes 5 debajo de cada barra. Si le encuentro una solución actualizo la respuesta.

## Alternativa muy complicada

Si necesitas que las etiquetas en x queden como en el histograma puedes adaptar algo así:

```
fi2 = unname(fi)

barplot(fi2,   #Le quité los nombres para que no etiquete por defaulf
        space = 0, #Para que las barras estén pegadas
        xlab = "Intervalos", ylab = "",
        col = "lightblue",
        main = "Frecuencias relativas")

axis(1, at = (L-1.945)*0.667, #Esto está calculado a ojo y no coincide perfecto, pero se podría arreglar. Sin esta transformación la etiquetas quedan desalienadas.
     labels = L)              #Por la transformación cambian los valores
```

La idea es hacer el gráfico sin las etiquetas y luego agregarlas con `axis`. Como no se ubican en el lugar correcto ajustarlas "a ojo" hasta que queden decentemente bien. No es muy sostenible si tienes que hacer muchos gráficos, pero si solo uno es un hack que soluciona el problema.

Comment: Vale, estaba dando por hecho que como `freq = TRUE` te devuelve el histograma de frecuencias absolutas, `freq = FALSE` te devolvería el de frecuencias relativas.

Comment: En realidad como etiquetas del eje X quería poner las marcas de clase de los intervalos, `## [1] 2.7 4.2 5.7 7.2 8.7`, pero con tu proporción también quedan bien.